# Catch and throw not working in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a number guessing game in Ruby but the program exits after I type in yes when I want to play again. I tried using the catch and throw but it would not work. Could I please get some help.

Here is my code.

```
class Game
    def Play
        catch (:start) do
            $a=rand(11)
            puts ($a)
            until $g==$a
                puts "Guess the number between 0-10."
                $g=gets.to_i
                if $g>$a
                    puts "The number you guessed is too high."
                elsif $g==$a
                    puts "Correct you won!!!"
                    puts "Would you like to play again?"
                    $s=gets()
                    if $s=="yes"
                        $c=true
                    end
                    if $c==true
                        throw (:start) 
                    end
                elsif $g<$a
                    puts "The number you guessed is too low."
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
Game.new.Play
```

---

**Edit:** Here's my new code after trying suggestions:

```
class Game
  def Play
    catch (:start) do
      $a=rand(11)
      puts ($a)
      while $s=="yes"
        until $g==$a
          puts "Guess the number between 0-10."
          $g=gets.chomp.to_i
          if $g>$a
            puts "The number you guessed is too high."
          elsif $g==$a
            puts "Correct you won!!!"
            puts "Would you like to play again?"
            $s=gets.chomp
            if $s=="yes"
              throw (:start)
            end
          elsif $g<$a
            puts "The number you guessed is too low."
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
Game.new.Play
```

Comment: I think it is obvious now after I reformatted your code.

Comment: Post this code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some pointers on style/scope/structure.

Comment: Catch doesn't work the way you think it does. Throwing `:start` here will just exit the `Play` method entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is here:

```
$s=gets()
if $s=="yes"
    $c=true
end
```

The `gets` method will read the next line including the new line character '\n', and you compare it to only "yes":

```
> gets
=> "yes\n"
```

The idiomatic way to fix this in Ruby is the `chomp` method:

```
> gets.chomp
=> "yes"
```

That said, your code has two other deficiencies.

1. You may come from a language such as PHP, Perl, or even just Bash scripting, but Ruby doesn't require the dollar sign before variables. Using a $ gives a variable global scope, which is likely not what you want. In fact, you almost never want a variable to have global scope.

   Ruby uses three types of symbol prefixes to indicate scope - @ for instance, @@ for class, and $ for global. However the most common type of variable is just local which doesn't need any prefix, and what I would suggest for your code.
2. I have always been told that it is very bad practice to use exceptions for control structure. Your code would be better served with a while/break structure.

Comment: I tired what you recommenced but my game would not loop if the player answered yes to playing again. Here is my new code. @kwarrick

Comment: {class Game
 
def Play
  catch (:start) do
  $a=rand(11)
  puts ($a)
   while $s=="yes"
    until $g==$a
    puts "Guess the number between 0-10."
    $g=gets.chomp.to_i
     if $g>$a
     puts "The number you guessed is too high."
     elsif
     $g==$a
     puts "Correct you won!!!"
     puts "Would you like to play again?"
     $s=gets.chomp
      if $s=="yes"
      throw (:start) 
      end
     elsif
     $g<$a
     puts "The number you guessed is too low."
     end
    end
   end
  end
 end
end

Game.new.Play
}

Answer (score 1):

When you do `gets()`, it retrieves the full line with a '\n' in the end. You need to trim the new line character by using:

```
$g=gets.chomp.to_i
```

Same for other `gets`

Comment: Mind leaving a comment why downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because `"1\n".to_i==1`; the problem is only with comparing to `"yes"`.

Comment: @Phrogz I only said a newline is included in gets, and I did mention he should change others as well

Comment: You are suggesting to make the code worse. `$g=gets.chomp.to_i` is worse than `$g=gets.to_i`.

Comment: @sawa and the reason is?

Comment: Because it is redundant. It involves an extra step. Why is writing `"foo".chomp.chomp.chomp.chomp` **not** worse than `"foo"` (which I disagree)? The reason is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated code (where you fixed the newline problem shown by others), your new problem is that you have wrapped all your game inside `while $s=="true"`. The very first time your code is run, `$s` is `nil` (it has never been set), and so you never get to play. If you used local variables instead of global variables (`s` instead of `$s`) this would have become more obvious, because the code would not even have run.

Here's one working way that I would re-write your game.

```
class Game
  def play
    keep_playing = true
    while keep_playing
      answer = rand(11)     # Make a new answer each time
      puts answer if $DEBUG # we don't normally let the user cheat
      loop do               # keep going until I break from the loop
        puts "Guess the number between 0-10."
        guess = gets.to_i   # no need for chomp here
        if guess>answer
          puts "The number you guessed is too high."
        elsif guess<answer
          puts "The number you guessed is too low."
        else
          puts "Correct you won!!!",
               "Would you like to play again?"
          keep_playing = gets.chomp.downcase=="yes"
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
Game.new.play
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really answer your question about why your code isn't working, but after seeing the code you posted I just had to refactor it. Here you go:

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @answer = rand(11)
  end

  def play
    loop do
      guess = get_guess
      display_feedback guess
      break if guess == @answer
    end
  end

  def self.play_loop
    loop do
      Game.new.play
      break unless play_again?
    end
  end

  private

  def get_guess
    puts "Guess the number between 0-10."
    return gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  def display_feedback(guess)
    if guess > @answer
      puts "The number you guessed is too high."
    elsif guess < @answer
      puts "The number you guessed is too low."
    elsif guess == @answer
      puts "Correct you won!!!"
    end
  end

  def self.play_again?
    puts "Would you like to play again?"
    return gets.chomp == "yes"
  end
end

Game.play_loop
```